# Listview Filter with SearchView Using Base Adapter in Xamarin android Error

Tags: xamarin.android

I am try to filter listview with searchview using Base Adapter in in xamarin Android, My listView Bind in sql server using restfull web service i am stuck in PublishResults which is given an error

Here Is My Code:-

GetHospNames.cs

```
   public class GetHospNames
{
    public string HospID { get; set; }
    public string HospName { get; set; }

    public GetHospNames(string HospID, string HospName)
    {
        this.HospID = HospID;
        this.HospName = HospName;
        //this.HospLogo = HospLogo;
    }
}
```

ContListViewHospNameClass.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using System.IO;
using Android.Content;
using Java.Lang;
using Android.Text;
using Java.Util;
using Oject = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace HSAPP
{

    public class ContListViewHospNameClass : BaseAdapter<GetHospNames>, IFilterable
    {
        public List<GetHospNames> objList;

        Activity objActivity;

        List<GetHospNames> filterList;
        public ContListViewHospNameClass(Activity objMyAct, List<GetHospNames> objMyList) : base()
        {
            this.objActivity = objMyAct;
            objList = objMyList;
            this.filterList = objList;
            Filter = new CustomFilter(this);

        }

        public override GetHospNames this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return objList[position];
            }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return objList.Count;
            }
        }

        public Filter Filter { get; set; }



        public override void NotifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            base.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        //This is Inner Class

        public class CustomFilter : Filter
        {
            ContListViewHospNameClass CustomAdapter;
            public CustomFilter(ContListViewHospNameClass adapter) : base()
            {
                this.CustomAdapter = adapter;
            }
            protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
            {


                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null && constraint.Length() > 0)
                {
                    //Contraint To Upper

                    List<GetHospNames> filter = new List<GetHospNames>();

                    foreach (GetHospNames name in CustomAdapter.objList)
                    {
                        if (name.HospName.ToUpper().Contains(constraint.ToString().ToUpper()))
                        {
                            filter.Add(name);
                        }
                    }
                    Oject[] Name;
                    Name = new Oject[filter.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < filter.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Name[i] = filter[i].HospName.ToString();
                    }

                    result.Count = filter.Count;
                    result.Values = Name;

                }
                return result;
            }

            protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults result)
            {


                List<GetHospNames> filteredList = new List<GetHospNames>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ((Oject[])result.Values).Length; i++)
                {

                    filteredList.Add((Oject[])result.Values[i]);//Here Is An Error *****Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Object'****
                }
                CustomAdapter.objList = filteredList;
                CustomAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }



        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }



        public Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] getByte)
        {
            if (getByte.Length != 0)
            {
                return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(getByte, 0, getByte.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            var item = objList[position];

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = objActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ContListViewHospName, null);
            }
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvHospID).Text = item.HospID;
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvHospName).Text = item.HospName;


            return convertView;
        }


    }
    public static class ObjectTypeHelper
    {
        public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
        {
            var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
            return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my MainActivity Code

```
private void BindControl_BindHospCompleted(object sender, BindControl.BindHospCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            jsonValue = e.Result.ToString();
            try
            {
                if (jsonValue == null)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "No Data For Bind", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    return;
                }

                JArrayValue = JArray.Parse(jsonValue);
                list = new List<GetHospNames>();
                int count = 0;
                while (count < JArrayValue.Count)
                {
                    GetHospNames getHospName = new GetHospNames(JArrayValue[count]["HospID"].ToString(), JArrayValue[count]["HospName"].ToString());
                    list.Add(getHospName);
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "No List Of Hospitals", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                adapter = new ContListViewHospNameClass(this, list);
                listView.Adapter = adapter;
                search.QueryTextChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);
            };
                listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
                pBar.Dismiss();
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
            {
                pBar.Dismiss();
                //Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();

                Finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChkIntConnActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Please Help...Thank You

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Its java.lang.object error in publishresult override mothod